# TFRecord larger than the original data

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

Actually, I am dealing with many pictures which are from different videos, so I use **tf.SequenceExample()** to save them as different sequences and their labels attached into TFRcord.

But after running my code to generate TFRecord, it generates **a TFRecord which is 29GB larger than my original pictures 3GB**.

Is that normal to create TFRecord larger than the original data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may be storing the decoded images instead of the jpeg encoded ones. TFRecord has no concept of image formats so you can use any encoding you want. To keep the size the same, convert the original image file contents to a `BytesList` and store that without calling `decode_image` or using any image libraries or anything that understands image formats.

Another possibility is you might be storing the image as an `Int64List` full of bytes which would be 8x the size. Instead, store it as a `BytesList` containing a single `Bytes`.

Answer (score 0):

Check the the type of data you load. I guess you load images as pixel-data. Every pixel is `unit8` (8 bit) and likely to be converted to `float` (32 bit). Hence you have to expect that it gets 4 times the original size (3 GB -> 12 GB).

Also, the original format might have (better) compression than tfrecords. (I'm not sure if tfrecords can use compression)

Comment: Thanks for answering, but in fact I have already cut some frames from my original pictures. The original videos each has more than 20 frames(some even 50 frames), I just use 10 of them to create sequence, but it's 8 times larger(3GB->29GB). I read pictures as [width,height,channel] and create a feature.float_list for every sequence and int64_list for its label

Comment: @hjw JPG is compressed. Have you tried storing those as BMP for a comparison? If all images stored as BMP are about 29GB, you know that my answer is correct. If the BMPs are < 28 GB you know that something is missing. If the BMPs are ~3GB, you know that my answer is wrong.

Comment: Ok, I will try. But I really want to know whether there is a way to make the size of tfrecord file equal or less than the original's

Comment: @hjw Then you should probably ask that.

Comment: tfrecords could use gzip compression.